# Horizontal Navbar with arrow buttons with html, css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, user-interface

How can I create a horizontal navbar with arrow buttons on it's sides like below. I searched a lot but I did not get what I needed. I'll be using it in my Vue.js project.

---

|<|  Page4   Page3  **Home**   Page1  Page2    |>|

---

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, did you mean pagination?
If no, please comment and i will edited it.

```js
const Pagination = {
  name: 'pagination',
  template: '#pagination',
    props: {
    maxVisibleButtons: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 3
    },
    totalPages: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    total: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    perPage: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    currentPage: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
  },
  computed: {
    startPage() {
      if (this.currentPage === 1) {
        return 1;
      }

      if (this.currentPage === this.totalPages) { 
        return this.totalPages - this.maxVisibleButtons + 1;
      }

      return this.currentPage - 1;

    },
    endPage() {
      
      return Math.min(this.startPage + this.maxVisibleButtons - 1, this.totalPages);
      
    },
    pages() {
      const range = [];

      for (let i = this.startPage; i <= this.endPage; i+= 1 ) {
        range.push({
          name: i,
          isDisabled: i === this.currentPage 
        });
      }

      return range;
    },
    isInFirstPage() {
      return this.currentPage === 1;
    },
    isInLastPage() {
      return this.currentPage === this.totalPages;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onClickFirstPage() {
      this.$emit('pagechanged', 1);
    },
    onClickPreviousPage() {
      this.$emit('pagechanged', this.currentPage - 1);
    },
    onClickPage(page) {
      this.$emit('pagechanged', page);
    },
    onClickNextPage() {
      this.$emit('pagechanged', this.currentPage + 1);
    },
    onClickLastPage() {
      this.$emit('pagechanged', this.totalPages);    
    },
    isPageActive(page) {
      return this.currentPage === page;
    },
  }
 };

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    pagination: Pagination,
  },
  data () {
    return {
      currentPage: 1,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onPageChange(page) {
      console.log(page)
      this.currentPage = page;
    }
  },
});
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.pagination {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.pagination-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4AAE9B;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<pagination
   :total-pages="11"
   :total="113"
   :per-page="10"
   :current-page="currentPage"
   @pagechanged="onPageChange"
 />
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="pagination">
 <ul class="pagination">
    <li 
      class="pagination-item"
    >
      <button 
        type="button" 
        @click="onClickFirstPage"
        :disabled="isInFirstPage"
        aria-label="Go to first page"
      >
        First
      </button>
    </li>

    <li
      class="pagination-item"
    >
      <button 
        type="button" 
        @click="onClickPreviousPage"
        :disabled="isInFirstPage"
        aria-label="Go to previous page"
      >
        Previous
      </button>
    </li>

    <li v-for="page in pages" class="pagination-item">
      <button 
        type="button" 
        @click="onClickPage(page.name)"
        :disabled="page.isDisabled"
        :class="{ active: isPageActive(page.name) }"
        :aria-label="`Go to page number ${page.name}`"
        
      >
        {{ page.name }}
      </button>
    </li>

    <li class="pagination-item">
      <button 
        type="button" 
        @click="onClickNextPage"
        :disabled="isInLastPage"
        aria-label="Go to next page"
      >
        Next
      </button>
    </li>

    <li class="pagination-item">
      <button 
        type="button" 
        @click="onClickLastPage"
        :disabled="isInLastPage"
        aria-label="Go to last page"
      >
        Last
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: God bless you my friend :)))    I did not know it's name

Comment: Alhamdulillah.. i am happy to help.

Comment: I need it to be scrollable horizontally too, since I'll be using it for navbar so that way it's responsive too.

Comment: i did not know, what you mean. scrollable page? or scrollable navbar?
i suggest you to make new question on stackoverflow with more detail that you need.